# Disable WRONG Phone number detection on iPhone

Tags: ios, css, safari

I am currently working on a website on which order-numbers for products are shown. The iPhone detects them as a phone number and links them. Is there a way to prevent this?

To be specific: is there a way to prevent the detection in certain divs or sections?

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

I know this, but there's no need to prevent the detection globally, because it is okay for phone numbers.

Any idea?

Comment: You could add `onclick='return false'` to the `div` or `section`. This will prevent that something happens if the user clicks on it.

Comment: But he should be able to click on links in that area :)

Comment: You could wrap the phone number in a `span` with this `onclick`.

Comment: But even if the span prevents the click, it won't prevent the link detection and rendering it as a link (optics) :(

Comment: Maybe you could just do some `css` hacks like `text-decoration: none !important` and `color: black` or something like that?

Comment: Yes, I guess I have to go that dirty way … Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to add the meta-tag you mention and then make phone numbers as links, such as:

```
<a href="tel:12345678">12345678</a>
```

Comment: I guess this might be a solution that either needs manual link building by not qualified editors in the cms or a bit of jquery fun to set the links client sided. I keep that in mind!